# I would like to know if is possible change the property z index of the shapes? Nokia maps API

Tags: javascript, here-api

I would like to know if it is possible to change the `z-index` property of the shapes?

I'm making the route above the circle shape but the route remains behind.

What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by altering the **zIndex** property of the [Polyline](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.Polyline.Properties.html), like all **MapObjects**, the **Polyline** is derived from [Object](http://developer.here.com/docs/maps_js/topics_api_pub/nokia.maps.map.Object.Properties.html) which is where the **zIndex** is defined.

If you have a Polyline like this:

```
var points = [
new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.2, 8.57),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.1299, 8.5680),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.0969, 8.4829),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.0819, 8.4856),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.0555, 8.4479),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.02, 8.43)
    ];

// Purple polyline
poly = new nokia.maps.map.Polyline(
    points,
    {   
        pen: {
            strokeColor: "#22CA", 
            lineWidth: 5
        }
    }
);
```

And any geoshape (e.g. a Polygon) like this:

```
gon = new nokia.maps.map.Polygon(
    [
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.2001, 8.6381),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.2190, 8.5474),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.2001, 8.5337),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.1799, 8.4774),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.1693, 8.4664),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.1522, 8.4657),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.1205, 8.5310),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.1363, 8.5879),
        new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(50.1882, 8.6168)

    ],
    {
        pen: { strokeColor: "#000", lineWidth: 1 },
        brush: { color: "#C22A" }
    }
);
```

Then the object that is placed on the map **first** will be at the back. By default both objects will have a **zIndex** of zero. If you increase the **zIndex** as shown:

```
poly.set("zIndex", 1)
```

Then it will move on top of all objects with the default **zIndex**

Comment: It seems that z-index is relative to the container (which also have z-index). So if you have objects in different containers, it could get tricky. I ended up changing the containers' z-index.